# Sharepoint sync

Tags: plugins

My company website is built on Craft CMS. We have a technical department publishing documentation for our products, so that our customer can download them without login. The department is editing and adding new documents weekly, and upload changes and new documents every week manually on our website will be a struggle.

Down to the point. We use Sharepoint in office 365 today. It's quite easy to updated documentation and keep track of revision history. Is it possible to create a page in our website where the latest update of these PDF/Documents in the library in Sharepoint is available for open download?

Answer (score 1):

Should be doable with a [custom](https://pluginfactory.io) [Craft plugin](https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins).

There are several [PHP Sharepoint](https://packagist.org/search/?q=sharepoint) libraries already available, but [this one](https://packagist.org/packages/vgrem/php-spo) looks promising.

But essentially your plugin would import the Sharepoint library, you'd point it to your Sharepoint web service endpoints and query for the docs that you're interested in, building URL endpoints where end-users could be able to download them from a Craft template.